# how to manually calculate SE of coeficient from regress data outputs

Tags: regression

[image]

Does anyone know how to manually calculate Std Error of Cig (x) from the given info from the above table?

Answer (score 1):

It's already right there in the output. There's nothing to calculate.

There's a column labelled "Standard error". There's a row labelled with the required variable name.

Comment: David was asking for a way to *manually* calculate the standard error.

Comment: The question clearly asks how to do it manually "...  ***from the given info*** from the above table". Given that the required quantity  is already *IN* the given info in that table, no additional calculation is required, we can already take it directly from the table. If the OP didn't want us to use that column, it would need to be omitted from the information given (i.e. if the OP intended to ask something other than what they asked they should clarify the question). I contend that my answer fulfills the requirements of the posed question and as far as I can discern was what the OP sought.

Comment: As you pointed out, the question doesn't make a lot of sense without assuming that the standard error column should not be used. But I guess you are still technically correct. I submitted an edit to clarify this.