# Manually calculate the parameters (Std. Error) of lm output in R

Tags: r, regression

I'm trying to expand my understanding of Linear regression and to that end I'm looking at calculating a Linear regression exercise by hand.

Using some dummy data

```
x <- c(17,13,12,15,16,14,16,16,18,19)
y <- c(94,73,59,80,93,85,66,79,77,91)
model.test <- lm(y ~ x)
summary(model.test)
```

The output gives me:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)   30.104     23.824   1.264    0.242  
x              3.179      1.514   2.100    0.069

Residual standard error: 9.859 on 8 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.3553,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2747
```

F-statistic: 4.409 on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: 0.06895

I can :

- manually calculate the estimates of the intercept and x ok
- I understand how to calculate the t value (i.e. estimate/Std. Error)
- I also understand how to perform the hypothesis test to obtain a p-value for the Pr(>|t|) column.

My question is how can I calculate the two values in the Std. Error column?

For good measure I had a look at the lm.R  code and I can see:

```
se <- sqrt(diag(R) * resvar)
resvar <- rss/rdf
rss <-sum(w * r^2)
rdf <- df[2L]
```

It looks like the formula is contained within sw, however I can't quite figure out what is happening as part of the terms resvar(residial variance?) or the square root of a matrix R from what I can gather.

Thanks in advance 
Jonathan

PS I found a related post however it does not contain an answer -> [how to manually calculate SE of coeficient from regress data outputs](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122432/how-to-manually-calculate-se-of-coeficient-from-regress-data-outputs)

PPS Manual workings below

```
observation X   Y   (x-x_mean)  (y-y_mean)  (x-x_mean)*(y-y_mean)   (x-x_mean)^2    (y-y_mean)^2    y_hat   y(hat) - y  y(hat) - y^2)
1           17  94  1.4 14.3    20.02   1.96    204.49  84.0024336  -9.997566399    99.9513339
2           13  73  -2.6    -6.7    17.42   6.76    44.89   71.32039595 -1.679604051    2.821069768
3           12  59  -3.6    -20.7   74.52   12.96   428.49  68.14988654 9.149886536 83.72042362
4           15  80  -0.6    0.3 -0.18   0.36    0.09    77.66141478 -2.338585225    5.468980855
5           16  93  0.4 13.3    5.32    0.16    176.89  80.83192419 -12.16807581    148.062069
6           14  85  -1.6    5.3 -8.48   2.56    28.09   74.49090536 -10.50909464    110.4410701
 7          16  66  0.4 -13.7   -5.48   0.16    187.69  80.83192419 14.83192419 219.9859751
 8          16  79  0.4 -0.7    -0.28   0.16    0.49    80.83192419 1.831924188 3.355946231
 9          18  77  2.4 -2.7    -6.48   5.76    7.29    87.17294301 10.17294301 103.4887696
10          19  91  3.4 11.3    38.42   11.56   127.69  90.34345243 -0.656547573    0.431054716

Total       156 797 3.55271E-15 -2.84217E-14    134.8   42.4    1206.1  795.6372042 -1.362795772    777.7266929
Mean        15.6    79.7    3.55271E-16 -2.84217E-15    13.48   4.24    120.61  79.56372042 -0.136279577    77.77266929
Std Dev     2.170509413 11.57631682 2.170509413 11.57631682 26.01030565 4.845341405 135.6597115 6.881620524 9.294807222 74.37605266
Variance    4.711111111 134.0111111 4.711111111 134.0111111 676.536 23.47733333 18403.55733 47.35670104 86.39344129 5531.797209
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From doing some additional digging I found the Standard error of the parameter b can be obtained using the following formula:

```
SE = sb1 = sqrt [ Σ(yi - ŷi)^2 / (n - 2) ] / sqrt [ Σ(xi - x)^2 ] [1]
```

The Standard error of the intercept a can be found using the following formula:

```
SE = sa1 = S_e sqrt (( 1/n ]) + (x_mean)^2 / Σ(xi - x_mean)^2)
```

The Std error for b computed manually is 1.514 (which looks the same as the R regression out)
The Std error for a computed manually is 23.827 (which is out by 0.003 I can only put this down to a rounding error on my behalf)

References:

[1] http://stattrek.com/regression/slope-confidence-interval.aspx?Tutorial=AP

[2] http://courses.ncssm.edu/math/Talks/PDFS/Standard%20Errors%20for%20Regression%20Equations.pdf